# Alt + D equivalent on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an Alt + D equivalent on a Mac.  Where in Firefox it goes directly to the address bar and highlights its contents.  I am growing tired of using my mouse to click the address bar.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: On Windows CTRL+L also take you to the "Location" bar. That's the mnemonic to remember: L for Location.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, I never knew about Alt + D also working. Typically I use Ctrl + L for location bar, and Ctrl + K for the search box. On Chrome, Ctrl + K will insert a ? in the location bar to ensure whatever you type is searched for.

Comment: Ctrl+K is also the hotkey for the search bar.  No helpful way to remember that other than it's next to "l" and the search bar is next to the location bar.

Comment: Yeah, the CTRL+K is important because it ensures that you're typing a search query rather than a URI.  It can matter, depending on the contents of your hosts file or the way your DNS search is setup (just to name a couple of examples).

Comment: CTRL+L exists in windows, but he ask about equal CTRL+D in Mac. So you Mean there is not equal for it?

Comment: It's really getting old, the ludicrous amount of commands that are the same on Windows and Linux, but have different key commands on MacOs. You can't just simply swap control and command, as many commands, like this, are swapped alt commands. I hate you Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Command-L on a Mac (the command key is the one with the Apple logo),  Almost any Windows command which uses the control key (like copy, cut, paste) uses the command key on a Mac.